# STM32F429-DISC1 White Screen Error

Tags: stm32f4

I just bought **STM32F429-DISC1** a few weeks ago.
I did the following:

- Turned it ON by connecting to my laptop.
- installed the drivers.
- and updated the firmware

Everything worked perfectly fine.

Then I put it in a box safely because I was busy with other things. Today, after a week or so **I connected it again and observed the following things::**

1. COM and PWR LEDs are RED (static).
2. The LCD Screen is stuck and completely white.
   (Image Attached)

**WHAT I CHECKED/Resolved ::**

- My device is still being detected by the PC as a Flash drive.
- I then Compiled and Loaded a LED Toggle program to check and it's running without any error.
- I tried using a different Cable and PC , but the problem persists.
- I tried to connect external 5V and 3V Sources,but the problem persists.
- My firmware and drivers are up to date.

**So , I draw the conclusion that the only problem is with the LCD screen. 
Can someone guide me with any solution (As soon as possible) ? 
Any help shall be appreciated[image].**

Comment: Are you sure that the LCD is still connected properly to the board? Perhaps its connector has come loose.

Comment: While physical damage may have *also* occured, the LCD would not work after loading an LED toggle program; it can only work when you load a program capable of operating it.  What you are talking to via USB is not running firmware on the STM32F429, but rather the on-board "ST-LINK" programmer.  This is a developer board; there is probably a demo that utilizes the LCD which you can find and re-load, but it is not really intended to have any end-user functionality, but rather only to let you start to develop capabilities with the technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is normal. The LCD will not display an image unless the firmware running on the target device has configured it.

By loading "a LED toggle program", you have erased the demonstration firmware which was displaying a user interface on the LCD. If you no longer have a copy of this firmware, [you can download it from ST's web site](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/mcu-mpu-embedded-software/stm32-embedded-software/stm32-standard-peripheral-library-expansion/stsw-stm32138.html). (A precompiled hex file is in the `Demonstration/Binary` directory.)